# How in Unity Turn base move

Tags: unity-game-engine, radix, turn

I'm noob in Unity. Can somebody help me pls? So. I have 2 or more characters on the board 9x12 cells. If I touch character, cells near him (left,right,back,back left,back right, front, front left, front right) must change color and activated. Then if I touch some of the activated cell, character must run with running animation to touched cell. If I touch not activated cell, character must stay on his position. If character 2 stay on cell near character 1 and I touch character 1, cells near character 1 must activated and change color, except cell on witch stay character 2. My English is poor, and this must be show what I want. https://youtu.be/FRwIreenNx8

So by my logic:
1. Touch character
2. Check if nearest 8 cells are busy by another character
2.1 not busy then cells change color
2.2 busy then cells not change color
3. Touch avalible only on not busy cells
4. Move using move animation to touched cell position
5. Use this logic to all characters

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [unity3d]! I think this article would help you understand what a good question can be on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I would like to see what kind of code you have so far, and if you can, narrow the question down to a specific problem that you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is a somewhat broad question. But here is part of a solution.

You could have a 2D array with the cells in.

A 2D array is a bit like a coordinate system.

It can look like this

```
[0,0][1,0][2,0]
[0,1][1,1][2,1]
[0,2][1,2][2,2]
```

Each of those cells can then hold an object.

That object could look like this:

```
Cell{

public Transform CurrentlyOnCell; //<- this is the player, if null then no one is there.
public int x; //cell x coordinate.
public int y; //cell y coordinate.

}
```

If you also have a manager class that holds all the cells. Then when clicking a cell you can send it to the manager class, get a collection of all surrounding cells and handle whether or not they should activate.

If there currently is an object on the cell (CurrentlyOnCell is not null), then it should not activate.

To stick with your logic steps:

1. Touch character should get the local cell script from the touched object (This can be done with Raycasting).
2. You can check the nearest 8 cells by sending that cell script to a manager knowing all cells. The manager then checks which ones are the surrounding ones based on the coordinates of the cell given.
3. The cell can be designated busy if the "Transform" variable it has is not null. Then it should not be activated.
4. Movement and animation are topics on their own and can be made in different ways. I advise you to google this. But basically your character should only be allowed to move to places that have space.
5. The script should be usable on multiple characters if you apply it to them inside Unity.

Further reading:

2D arrays: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

---

**Comments**

My advice above is not a finished solution, it is meant to inspire you on how to solve the tasks you mention though.

I will advise you to break down what it is you wish to do so you don't take too many things at once.

Don't try to animate, move and activate cells all at once. It will become too big for you to make in one attempt when you are new at using Unity.

Here are some steps to consider. It is better to break it down into simple acts instead of wanting to do many complex things at once.

1. Find out how to find the cell when you click on it (look up Raycasting).
2. Find out how to get surrounding cells of that cell.
3. Find out how to activate the correct cells.
4. Find out how to deactivate the surrounding cells again.
5. Find out how to move your game object to that cell and then deactivate the surrounding cells.
6. Find out how to use animation.
7. Find out how to apply animation when you move and to stop it when you stop moving.

I wish you good luck in your future learning process.

Comment: Thank you Doh09 for your advice. I'll try to use it to get the result